# Updating Android application. Small Update

Tags: android, apk, ogg

I have a soundboard application that I occasionally update by adding more .ogg files. As of now the application is 8MB which is not a small application for the user. The problem I have is that when I release the new version the user has to download the entire apk again. Downloading 8mb every time I want to add 2 new sound files is a pain for my users especially if they are update over 3G where the download can take several minutes.

My question is this... is there any way to push out small updates that include the new sound files from the RAW folder and a couple changes to some class files without having the user to download the entire APK file? Thanks.

-J

Comment: This would not be a real "Market Update." This would be some sort of data retrieval done on your app, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can't push out a "differential" update to the Market, no. To accomplish what you're suggesting you would need to store the .ogg files on a server somewhere and have your application check for new files on each launch. If found, your application could then download the new files into its own local file space for use.

If your application isn't insanely popular, you can simply use [DropBox](http://db.tt/w4zOovG) to host your files (in your Public folder).